# Why is more angular momentum required to stabilize the orientation of a heavier bullet?

Tags: projectile

It's often stated that "heavier" bullets require more "spin" to stabilize vs. "lighter" ones.  My question is whether this is really a matter of *mass*.  I'm assuming that the destabilizing forces/torques are primary aerodynamic and that those aerodynamics are almost entirely a function of bullet shape, not bullet mass.

If two bullets are identical in shape and differ only in density, would the heavier one *really* need more angular momentum to keep it stable during its flight?

Comment: Won't the heavier one have more angular momentum if they are fired with the same velocity from a barrel with the same twist? If it doesn't have more, then it is going slower or is from a different barrel and will have different ballistics.

Comment: I should have said "all other initial conditions (aside from bullet mass) being equal", in which case a bullet with more mass will not be accelerated to the same muzzle velocity.  For a given twist, lower muzzle velocity will result in lower angular velocity, so that might be the answer if the increase in angular momentum due to extra bullet mass is less than the decrease in angular momentum due lower angular velocity.

Comment: Clarifying above comment, maybe the *same* angular momentum is required to stabilize the denser (but otherwise identical) bullet, but achieving it requires higher barrel twist because the heavier bullet won't accelerate to the same velocity.  If so, "heavier bullets require a barrel with more twist" not "heavier bullets require more angular momentum."